# Authentication on an empty mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I have created an empty mvc project using a database first approach i am using a user table (not netuser) for authentication purpose ...anyone please help me in adding authentication based on user in empty mvc authentication .thanks in advance

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

Comment: Please elaborate what you have done briefly (including technologies & frameworks used) and what you intend to do clearly.

Comment: Hi manish instead of using aspnetusers i want to use my tables for the purpose of authentication like login and registration